# Switch widget: onClick event works but how to listen when you slide the switch?

Tags: onclick, widget, switch-statement, ontouchlistener

I have a switch widget as per XML below and have onToggleClicked function which is working fine when you click on switch. But What I noticed is that you can actually slide the switch from one position to another and onClick event is not triggered in his case. How to disable sliding of the switch or how to monitor state change of the switch??
thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm interesting in finding out the answer to this too. What's going on? Is it a bug or what? I'm using API 19.

Answer (score 5):

There is only one way I have found to listen to the sliding event of the switch, using an OnCheckedChangeListener from the class CompoundButton. Like this, for example:

```
exampleSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.exampleSwitchID);
exampleSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            //your actions when the button has changed the status
            //the boolean isChecked tells you if the button is activated or not
        }
    };);
```

The only problem this might have is, if you change the state of the button programatically (exampleSwitch.setChecked(boolean)) it will fire the listener. If you don't want that to happen, before setting the state of the button set the listener to null. For example:

```
exampleSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
exampleSwitch.setChecked(boolean);
exampleSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);
```

I hope this help.